# Need to modify my input file

Tags: awk

1 - I've an input file as follows that has millions of records

```
w02_2017,1000550,10,0.76466668138703,0.96466668138703
w02_2017,10015774,10,3.878170108564,0.8634510325692
```

2 - So, I've written a script in bash which has 2 variables

```
+ dt=02_2017
+ dtid=20180217
```

3 - So, I loop this by

```
egrep -i $dt <input file> | sed -e "s/"$dt"/"$dtid"/g;s/w//g"
```

4 - I get the desired output as follows

```
20180217,1000550,10,0.76466668138703,0.96466668138703
20180217,10015774,10,3.878170108564,0.8634510325692
```

5.The problem is the above code takes a long time. How do I re-write this in `awk`, which I'm sure will be much quicker? 
        Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your goal? Extract and replace occurrences; or rewrite the whole file replacing occurrences? Have you tried just `sed -I -e "s/"$dt"/"$dtid"/g;s/w//g" <filename>`?

Comment: Please wrap your sample Inputs and expected outputs into CODE TAGS, you could see button `{}` while doing a post.

Comment: You said `I loop this...` - do you have a loop in your surrounding code that you haven't shown us? If so include it. You are using variables for the old and new strings - is that because those strings change? If so include the details of that in your problem description and example. The more effort you put into asking the question the better chance you have of getting the right answer.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. As you can see I'm grepping the value of $dt from the input file and the result of that grep changing the old string to new string. Yes, I'm looping this with many old strings to new strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "so I loop this" statements seems to be implying that you are looping over multiple values of `dt` and processing each in turn.  Just remove the `while read` loop and put the logic in a `sed` script instead; and process the file only once.

If you have

```
while read dt dtid; do
    egrep "$dt" "$inputfile" | sed "s/$dt/$dtid/;s/^w//"
done <<'____HERE' >output
   02_2017  20180217
   one      eins
   two      zwei
____HERE
```

you can firstly refactor to avoid the [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) (and note also that POSIX basically replaced `egrep` with `grep -E` some decades ago):

```
while read dt dtid; do
    sed -n "/$dt/!d;s/$dt/$dtid/;s/^w//;p' "$inputfile"
...
```

but secondly just replace it all with a single `sed` script, and only process the entire file once, without any shell loop:

```
sed -e 's/02_2017/20180217/' \
    -e 's/one/eins/' \
    -e 's/two/zwei/' \
    -e 's/^w//' "$inputfile" >output
```

If you only want to print the lines on which a substitution happened, have a look at the `t` command in `sed`.

Comment: That is exactly what I do but not sure whether using awk will make the process run faster.

Comment: Removing the shell loop and processing the file only once will improve performance by several factors. The speed difference between Awk and `sed` will be negligible by comparison. In trivial cases `sed` can be expected to be a little bit faster because it is simpler, but sometimes you see the opposite, and often you can write more intelligent scripts in Awk.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `sed` will be faster than `awk` in dealing with this many records. Nevertheless, you are doing multiple iterations that can be done in a single iteration.

```
$ dt="w02_2017"
$ dtid="20180217"
$ sed -i "s/$dt/$dtid/g" largeInputFile
```

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you on same:

```
dt=02_2017
dtid=20180217
awk -v dt_val="$dt" -v dtid_val="$dtid"  '{gsub(dt_val,dtid_val)} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Since my `awk` is old version so I am using above, in case your `awk` is of newer version then you could `awk`'s option `-i inplace` too as follows:

```
dt=02_2017
dtid=20180217
awk  -i inplace  -v dt_val="$dt" -v dtid_val="$dtid"  '{gsub(dt_val,dtid_val)} 1' Input_file
```